# php variable in input value

Tags: php, html, paypal, express-checkout

I am a beginner and I am trying to integrate Paypal into my website.
In my cart there is a table which displays the total amount:

```
<td class="total_amount"><b>'.$_POST['amount'].'</b></td>
```

Now, I want to retrieve this amount and send it to paypal:

```
<form action="paypal_ec_redirect.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" value="'.$_GET['amount'].'"></input>
```

This doesn't work and am having errors:

> SetExpressCheckout API call failed. Detailed Error Message: Order
>   total is missing.Short Error Message: Transaction refused because of
>   an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.Error
>   Code: 10400Error Severity Code: Error

Help please.

Comment: Hi there - Please could you let us have a little more of you code. Please could you also tell us if you are using a .php file?

Comment: Well your using both _POST and _GET, I'd imagine you only want one of those. If you change the _GET to _POST does it work then?

Comment: Yes its .php file. Changing _GET to _POST does not work either. 
If I enter a value in the code like for example value="12", it works but thats not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`<td class="total_amount"><b> <?=$_POST['amount'] ?></b></td>`

and

`<form action="paypal_ec_redirect.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT" value=" <?=$_POST['amount'] ?>"></input>`

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but I am still having errors.